# Insert JSON into Table using MySQL Workbench 6.3 or SQL Server 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I've got some JSON bank statement code that I need to insert into a table but I'm having trouble with how I would do this on SQL server 2012, as it seems possible on 2016+ but not on 2012.

Either on there or MySQL would be ok - for reference, please see the code below. I think I would need two tables for the first and second part of the JSON file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to handle files like this? the first line with `name`, `status`, `location`, etc' are included just once, but the rest is repeated multiple times throughout the statements.

Please see below for an imitation test sample/reference of the JSON file/contents :

> { "status": "success","Name": "Theresa May","Location": "87654321","AccountCategory": "Business","AccountType": "Current","TicketNo": "12345-12","AvailableBal": "12775.0400","BookBa": "123475.0400","TotalCredit": "1234567","TotalDebit": "0","Usage": "5","Period": "May 11 2014 to Jul 11 2014","Currency": "GBP","Applicants": "Angel","Signatories": [{"Name": "Not Available","BVB":"Not Available"}],"Details": [{"PTransactionDate":"24-Jul-14","PValueDate":"24-Jul-13","PNarration":"Cash Deposit","PCredit":"0.0000","PDebit":"40003.0000","PBalance":"40003.0000"},{"PTransactionDate":"24-Jul-14","PValueDate":"23-Jul-14","PTest":"Cash Deposit","PCredit":"0.0000","PDebit":"40003.0000","PBalance":"40003.0000"},{"PTransactionDate":"25-Jul-14","PValueDate":"22-Jul-14","PTest":"Cash Deposit","PCredit":"0.0000","PDebit":"40003.0000","PBalance":"40003.0000"},{"PTransactionDate":"25-Jul-14","PValueDate":"21-Jul-14","PTest":"Cash Deposit","PCredit":"0.0000","PDebit":"40003.0000","PBalance":"40003.0000"},{"PTransactionDate":"25-Jul-14","PValueDate":"20-Jul-14","PTest":"Cash Deposit","PCredit":"0.0000","PDebit":"40003.0000","PBalance":"40003.0000"}]}

Comment: Sorry to say, your question's title is the equivalent of "Travel to Paris via an airport or via train." Workbench is a desktop client program that talks to MySQL. The equivalent for SQL Server is SQL Server Management Studio.  MySQL and SQL Server are somewhat different in the way they handle JSON. Do you want the JSON text stored in the DBMS, or do you want to use tables with columns named for your serialized Javascript objects? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any in built parsing for JSON prior to 2016; prior to that you would either need to use a CLR and use a solution on the internet (which tend to be slow and quirky). If you have to use SQL Server 2012, I suggest using an application to parse the data; and if needed feed it back to the server so you can store it in a parsable format.

Comment: @O.Jones Hi, thanks for your reply. To clarify, what I meant by this was that I want to get it into either my SQL Server 2012 environment, into a database, and into a table with columns for everything from 'Status' , 'Name' , etc.. until PBalance' whihc is the last one, and populate these fields with different JSON Bank Statements using SSMS.
 -OR, 
Another option if this is not possible is to use MySQL Workbench to input these JSON files in the same way to my Schemas > Tables with columns also, but using MySQL Workbench 6.3. Thanks